# How to use atos to properly symbolicate addresses from OSReportWithBacktrace?

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extension, darwin, xnu

I am trying to hunt down retain leaks in an open-source project to support I2C based trackpads (https://github.com/kprinssu/VoodooI2CHID).

The reason why I believe that there are retain leaks is because when I attempt to unload the kernel extension via the following commands:

```
sudo kextunload -verbose 6 VoodooI2CHID.kext
```

I get the following output:

```
Kext user-space log filter changed from 0xff2 to 0xfff.
Kext kernel-space log filter changed from 0xff2 to 0xfff.
Kext library architecture set to x86_64.
Requesting unload of com.alexandred.VoodooI2CHID (with termnation of IOServices).
(kernel) User-space log flags changed from 0x0 to 0xfff.
(kernel) Received 'Unload' request from user space.
(kernel) Rescheduling scan for unused kexts in 60 seconds.
(kernel) Can't unload kext com.alexandred.VoodooI2CHID; classes have instances:
(kernel)     Kext com.alexandred.VoodooI2CHID class VoodooI2CPrecisionTouchpadHIDEventDriver has 1 instance.
(kernel)     Kext com.alexandred.VoodooI2CHID class VoodooI2CMultitouchHIDEventDriver has 1 instance.
Kernel error handling kext request - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).
Failed to unload com.alexandred.VoodooI2CHID - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).
```

I came across pmdj's excellent answer on tracking down retain leaks ([Can't Unload Kernel Extension; Classes Have Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536970/cant-unload-kernel-extension-classes-have-instances)). I verfied that my situation is the second case via ioreg (classes are being terminated but are not properly freed). Additionally, I used pmdj's hint by overiding taggedRelease and taggedRetain (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471512/48660) to print the stack trace of the function calls.

Here's where I run into problems, I cannot use `atos` to convert the hex addresses back into human readable symbols. I use the follow command to generate the symbols:

`atos -arch x86_x64 -o VoodooI2C.kext/Contents/MacOS/VoodooI2C -l 0xffffff7f8432b000 0xffffff804588dfa0`

The load address parameter is retrieved from `kextstat` and  I expect the `-l` argument should handle the slide arithmetic.

`atos` should return a valid symbol but all I get is the hex address back. In the above example, I get `0xffffff804588dfa0` as the output. Can anybody point out what I exactly I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `kextstat` and `OSReportWithBacktrace` report unslid addresses, so KASLR is not your problem.

Notice that your kext is apparently loaded at `0xffffff7f8432b000`, whereas your backtrace frame address is `0xffffff804588dfa0`. This is quite far apart, and indeed kexts are always loaded in the `0xffffff7f8???????` (unslid) range, so `0xffffff804588dfa0` can't be anywhere near kext code. (the offset is about 3GB) It's almost certainly a function in the kernel proper. If you use `atos` with the appropriate running kernel's binary, it should be able to locate which one. For example:

```
atos -o /Library/Developer/KDKs/KDK_10.14.5_18F132.kdk/System/Library/Kernels/kernel 0xffffff804588dfa0
```

(I don't know what kernel version you are using, and this address doesn't seem to be meaningful in the 18F132 kernel, but you get the idea.)

Comment: Although the address I was provided was incorrect. The addresses from OSReportWithBacktrace are indeed coming from the kernel. I am finally seeing the symbols that I expect, thank you!

In addition, to help anybody else with a similar problem, use kextstat to check if the address lies under or over the first and last loaded address range. This helped me considerably find which binary to point atos to.